# If not now, when?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Gee, am I surprised that AFAIK, no one on M.Y. has ever asked for the answer to this question.

In *Pirkei Avot* 1:14, Hillel says, "If not now, when?"

O.K. I'm going to do a test .. I'm giving Hillel 3 seconds to answer the question...

3...2...1...NOW!

Hmmm ... still no answer. It's still not now...

So, I just proved the "If" part was true. It's not now. But the (implied) "then" part is a question - when? So, what's the answer? When???

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 4):

Later. When I get around to it.

Comment: OK. Wake me from my stupor...

Comment: https://www.etsy.com/listing/183489409/a-round-tuit-letterpress-coasters-set-of